# Как сделать background так же на всю ширину экрана как и на этом сайте

Tags: html, css

Как сделать background так же на всю ширину экрана как и на этом сайте
https://www.certilogo.com/extnfc?rk=2y10TtNjAWUNScyna0YZdVsfDemQl8z8zcjkHAt34CqDrQeFp066HhRjq&referrer=bluebite

Comment: `background-size: contain`?

Comment: Варианты есть - один на jquery http://coderhs.com/example/js/fullbg/ ну и на css3 http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size , как уже сказали)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если вопрос именно про как отследить ширину экрана, то используйте единицу измерения `vh`. Создайте контейнер с шириной 100% и высотой в 100vh и он растянется как на данном сайте. Далее поместите еще один блок внутрь с высотой 100% и шириной 100%. и на фон ставите изображение с `background-size:cover`